# Open modal cart after cart is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I want to **add two different products** (A & B) to the cart with one "Add to cart" button while beeing on product page A. Each product has **custom properties** that also need to be transmitted to the cart.
We use the **"modal" cart** option.

Found this piece of code on [github](https://gist.github.com/mig1098/0b0bf19900dce8584331):

```
var MGUtil = {
    data: [],
    ini: 0,
    total: 0,
    addItem: function(qty, id, properties, callback) {
        var params = { quantity: qty, id: id };
        if (properties != false) {
            params.properties = properties;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: params,
            success: function() {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback();
                }
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    },

    recursive: function() {
        MGUtil.addItem(MGUtil.data[MGUtil.ini].qty, MGUtil.data[MGUtil.ini].id, MGUtil.data[MGUtil.ini].properties, function() {
            MGUtil.ini += 1;
            if (MGUtil.ini < MGUtil.total) {
                MGUtil.recursive();
            } else {
                document.location.href = '/cart';//GO TO THE CART AFTER ADDING ITEMS
            }
        });
    },

    begin: function() {
        /*SAMPLE*/
        /* SET YOUR ARRAY QTY's' ID's PROPERTIES(FALSE IF IS EMPTY)*/
        MGUtil.data = [
            { "id": "#variant_id_A", "qty": 2, "properties": { "data1": "1" } },
            { "id": "#variant_id_B", "qty": 3, "properties": { "data2": "1" } }
        ];
        MGUtil.total = MGUtil.data.length;
        MGUtil.recursive();
    }
}

MGUtil.begin();
```

Only thing missing is that i want to open the "modal" cart and not go to the cart page.

I can show the cart with:

```
$('#ajaxifyModal').addClass('is-visible');
```

but the content is not updated when i do that on the product page after running the code above. Refreshing the page would be one solution - not very pretty one though.

How can i update the cart content and open the modal cart while not leaving the page?

**Update**

Think this is the AJAX call to receive the updated cart content:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(cart) {
        console.log(cart);
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

Comment: When exactly are you executing this function: $('#ajaxifyModal').addClass('is-visible'); ? It should  replace the "GO TO THE CART AFTER ADDING ITEMS" line of code. Is that what you have done? Or are you calling it right after you execute the "MGUtil.begin();" function?

Comment: i tried replacing the `else` part in the recursive function which doesn't work. I mean it "works" but the cart is empty. I also tried to trigger it manually a few secs after running the "add to cart" function - still empty

Comment: Ah okay, I thought it might be async issue but it's obviously not...

Comment: I guess the question is how to trigger re-render (in shopify? or is this custom code?) before opening the `#ajaxifyModal`.

Comment: it is shopify - the code is custom but works. As you said the only issue is how to do the "AJAX call that calls for the cart to be updated on the current page".

Comment: Can you tell me what do you receive from "success: function(cart)" -> 'cart' variable.

Comment: The cart as json: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#get-cart

Comment: You have an empty error function?  How do you know you're not getting errors?

Comment: so, inside the `else` you place the last `ajax` function you posted, inside that function's success is where you are supposed to try and show the modal, so instead of `console.log(cart);`, what are you doing in there right now?

Comment: @RandomDude Its a conventional jquery thing. You need to manually update the cart view by picking up the display boxes and the data received in the CART GET request Success function where you have placed console.log(cart).
Further can be done if you post the other pieces of code like the html structure of modal and the cart json details.

Answer (score 0):

try replace your "else" with this one here

```
else {
  var tmpVar = $.get("/cart"); // trying to trigger the page (we are not going to do anything with this variable)
  $('#ajaxifyModal').addClass('is-visible'); // open the modal
}
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, doesn't work. I can see that the default AddToCart consists of 3 AJAX calls: POST request to "/cart", GET request to "/cart.js" and GET request to "/cart". Tried to trigger the 2nd and 3rd manually before and always failed. I assume that i have to somehow trigger a "cart rebuild" with the response of GET "/cart" (or "/cart.js"). Does that make sense?

Comment: Okey, got it... you get the card with [GET /cart.js](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#get-cart) but you never update the values in the modal. can you give me the modal code so i can write something to updated?

Comment: have a look at our staging: https://welovestaging.myshopify.com/ - password: freemp

Comment: two variant ids for testing: 7060944977963, 7060878753835 (replace #variant_id_A, #variant_id_B in the code i posted)